# Error: ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo este código

```
protdeg = {"A":4,"C":2,"D":2,"E":2,"F":2,"G":4,"H":2,"I":3,"K":2,"L":6,"M":1,"N":2,"P":4,"Q":2,"R":6,"S":6,"T":4,"V":4,"W":1,"Y":2}
protseq = input("Protein sequence: ").upper()

segsvalues = []

for aa in range(len(protseq)):
    segment = protseq[aa:aa+15]
    degen = 0

    if len(segment)==15:
        for x in segment:
            degen += protdeg.get(x,3.05)
        segsvalues.append(degen)
    else:
        pass
min_value = min(segsvalues)
minpos = segsvalues.index(min_value)
print (protseq[minpos:minpos+15])
```

Al introducir mi secuencia para que tenga la asignación de valores de degeneración me indica que `segsvalues` es una secuencia vacía. *¿Cómo podría corregir este error?*

Gracias.

Comment: Tienes dos variables con nombres parecidos, `segsvalores` y `segsvalues`. Fijate que le agregas valores a `segvalues` pero en vez de usarlo como argumento de `min` usas `segvalores` (que está vacio).

Comment: braver: tenías razón, jaja, perdón el espanglish (ya la corregí), pero de todos modos me arroja el mismo error ):

Comment: ¿Qué deberia pasar si la entrada tiene longitud menor a 15? Como el `for` la parte en segmentos de longitud 15 y en el `if` no agrega nada cuando el segmento es menor a esa longitud, `segvalues` va a estar vacio para cuando se ejecute el `min`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probe el código usando

```
protseq = "TTLLSETLSEVRGLGTSAQTPPHIKEYIIGIPMSIIHLNVVCRAAMFNAQMQVMVGEAMW" \
          "DWQAMYPRDTFLVMFPIHWPAQNDHPSKQSWDPIYTLFFKNSWFMQPATPRLNKHSVYAW" \
          "YWDRKRVN"
```

y acortandolo un caracter hasta ver donde se caía. Como se ha dicho en los comentarios, el problema se produce cuando `protseq` mide menos de 15 caracteres de largo, pues nunca se ejecuta este `if`, que es el único punto donde se hace crecer `segsvalues`.

```
if len(segment)==15:
   for x in segment:
   degen += protdeg.get(x,3.05)
   segsvalues.append(degen)
```

Suponiendo que el algoritmo sólo funciona para secuencias de proteínas de largo 15 o superior, hay que ejecutar los cálculos finales sólo si hay datos, así:

```
if segsvalues:
    min_value = min(segsvalues)
    minpos = segsvalues.index(min_value)
    print (protseq[minpos:minpos+15])
else:
    print("Proteina demasiado corta. (Ingrese 15 o más caracteres)")
```